# How to make your bot say things from chat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to talk through my discord but I'm not sure on how to code such a thing; here is what I have tried.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Mike = Bot(command_prefix=",")

@Mike.command()
    async def Msay(*args, message):
        Mike.delete_message(message)
        return await Mike.say(args)

Mike.run(secrets.BOT_TOKEN)
```

I want to be able to type in my discord chat

ME: ,Msay hello world

**My Message deleted**

Mike-Bot: hello world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Mike = Bot(',')

@Mike.command(pass_context = True)
async def Msay(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await Mike.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await Mike.say(mesg)

Mike.run(Token)
```

Comment: @saurav Your bot's token. You get that from selecting your bot here https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/me and revealing token. Its how you run your bot.